# How to call common name method of two Sub-Classes from Superclass?

Tags: c#, class

During my daily work time, I came across one problem:

Suppose:

1. we have a object **A**, it's `Object` type
2. **A** maybe type `B` or type `C`
3. type `B` and `C` has a same name method `GetSomething()`
4. <del>we don't know whether `B` and `C` both implementation the same interface(which means we do not know relationship between them)</del>
5. type `B` and `C` inherit from `Object` which means nothing help. Apart from the same method name, we know nothing about type `B` and `C`

The question is, I want to call `GetSomething` from A, no matter what type it is:

```
//Object A maybe type B or C
//both B and C can call method
//but we just don't know type of A
var result=A.GetSomething();
```

If you meet this scenario, what would you do?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of object oriented programming that it doesn't matter? The "right" method will be called because the type of A is known when the call is made?... Maybe I don't understand your question? Could be that I can't decode `we don't know whether B and C both implementation the same interface` - as shown, there _is_ no "interface" in the sense that the method is called without parameters. I don't understand your question / problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think the OP means he knows there will be a GetSomething method, but not necessarily as an implementation of a given interface.  If this is the case, then I'd suggest looking at calling methods by name using reflection

Comment: are you refering to calling the methods in the super class or outside the class hierachi? Can you change the implementation of the super lass?

Comment: @RuneFS thanks. Actually, I cannot charge in anything, because I used third-party control. And of course I can ask official for help, I just want to figure out if I come across this situation, and I couldn't get help from outside, what can I do?

Comment: have a look at my answer for different ways of solving this (including some where you don't need to change the super class)

Comment: in the question you say _...we do not know relationship between them..._ but the title references "superclass" - do you want to update one or another?

Comment: great - although, in C# most things derive from `Object` (apart from interfaces and pointers), so when people talk about two different types they don't normally say the types share the same "superclass" (although technically they do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to beg for an abstract method

```
public abstract class A {
   protected abstract object GetSomething();
}
```

in each derived class you'd then need to implement GetSomething() e.g.

```
public class B : A {
   protected override object GetSomeTHing(){
      //implementation goes here
   }
}
```

you can then freely call `GetSomething()` anywhere in the implementation of the super class (`A`)

if you are not looking for a way to call it from within the implementation of the super class but somewhere else you basically have three options

- Change the implementation of the super class to include a (potential abstract) definition of the method
- Use dynamic typing
- Use reflection

The former is basically the same as the above example (just make the access modifier `public`instead of `protected`)

The 2nd and 3rd options both suffer from the same downside. They are not compile time typed so you might (will) once in a while during development have runtime errors instead of compile time errors. If you have a high test coverage that shouldn't be too much of a problem though.

I'd prefer using dynamic typing because it's easier to read and write than the reflection version. Assuming `GetSomething` returns an int it would look like this

int result = ((dynamic)A).GetSomething();

I've change result to be explicitly type instead of implicitly typed because it will otherwise be typed as `dynamic` resulting in any expressions involving result to also be typed dynamic. If you know the return type of `GetSomething` you are better of telling the compiler that up front

Answer (score 1):

> - type B and C has a same name method GetSomething()
> - we don't know whether B and C both implement the same interface

You don't know, but can you change it? Because the most logical solution would be to describe the "something" behavior in an interface:

```
interface IHasSomething
{
    Something GetSomething();
}
```

And applying that to classes B and C.

Given your B and C instances are declared as `object`, you can try to test whether they implement this interface:

```
var something = obj as IHasSomething
if (something != null)
{
    var youWereLookingFor = something.GetSomething();
}
```

Or you can try using Reflection, which always should be a last resort as opposed to good OO design (what if you want to add parameters and/or overloads, call another method, use a different return type, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

If `A` does not have the method you should not try to think about doing it since it is bad design and against OOP principles. However if you absolutely must do it like that you can try using reflection:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetSomething", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if(methodInfo != null)
   result = methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] {});
```

However I strongly recommend the use of an abstract class or using a default `GetSomething()` in your `A` class...

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of. Straight-up check if the type of 'a' implements an expected type:

```
if(a is B)
{
    ((B)a).GetSomething();
}
else if(a is C)
{
    ((C)a).GetSomething();
}
```

Otherwise, cast to a to dynamic, and call the function that on that. This will throw if the function can't be found.

```
dynamic dA = a;
int result;
try
{
    result = dA.GetSomething();
}
catch(RuntimeBinderException ex)
{
    // a was of a type that doesn't have GetSomething
}
```

The first example is OK to use, the second dynamic example should be considered as an example only unless it's a last resort. Please try to use an abstract class or interface which defines `GetSomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

In a good architecture, you have access to the method via an interface or common base class.

If you really want/need to that anyway, then what you are trying to do is called *[duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)*. You can use the `dynamic` keyword or reflection.